# Count Calculation using PIVOT IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the number of stock and no-stock using pivot. Is this possible with SQL Server 2008?

Table:

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE
(
    ID INT, 
    PRODUCT VARCHAR (35),
    SKU INT,
    NEWPRICE DECIMAL(10,5),
    OLDPRICEEX DECIMAL(10,5),
    REMARKS VARCHAR (35)
)

INSERT @MYTABLE
    SELECT 438, 'RESISTOR', 43822,  12.66,  11.13,  'STOCK' UNION ALL
    SELECT 438, 'RESISTOR', 43870,  11.99,  12.30,  'OUTS-STOCK' UNION ALL
    SELECT 719, 'INDUCTOR', 71911,  666.66, 764.16, 'OUTS-STOCK' UNION ALL
    SELECT 101, 'CAPACITOR',10159,  22.66,  19.12,  'STOCK' UNION ALL
    SELECT 101, 'CAPACITOR',10159,  19.32,  18.19,  'STOCK'
```

Expected output

```
ID  | PRODUCT   | STOCK | OUT-STOCK
----+-----------+-------+----------
438 | RESISTOR  |   1   |     1
719 | INDUCTOR  |   0   |     1
101 | CAPACITOR |   2   |     0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of Pivot. USe below query.

```
 SELECT ID,Product, SUM(case when REMARKS ='STOCK' then 1 else 0 end) as STOCK,
            SUM(case when REMARKS ='OUTS-STOCK' then 1 else 0 end) as [OUT-STOCK]
 FROM @MYTABLE
 GROUP BY ID,Product
```

Answer (score 1):

Using PIVOT:

```
Select * from
(Select ID As ForCnt, ID, PRODUCT, REMARKS  from @MYTABLE) a
PIVOT
(
COUNT(ForCnt) FOR REMARKS IN ([STOCK], [OUTS-STOCK])
) x
```